# How Can I get term/ category name wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I am using WordPress plugin Taxonomy images. I'm using it to get images for taxonomies.

From the below code I am getting the images and link. I want to get category name with these images. Here is my code. How can I get category name?

```
<?php 
$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array( 'taxonomy' => 'category', ) ); 

if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {     
    print '<div class="row">';     
    foreach ( (array) $terms as $term ) { 
        print '<div class="col-sm-3"><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term, $term->taxonomy ) ) . '">' . wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, ' ' ) . '</div>';
    }     
    print '</div>'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: <?php 
  $terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array(     'taxonomy'     => 'category', ) ); if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {     print '<div class="row">';     foreach ( (array) $terms as $term ) {         print '<div class="col-sm-3"><a href="' . esc_url(       get_term_link( $term, $term->taxonomy ) ) . '">' . wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, ' ' ) . '</div>';     }     print '</div>'; }

               ?>

Comment: `$term->name` <-- try that

Comment: $term->name not working

Comment: After the `foreach` do `var_dump($term)` and paste here what you get.

Comment: object(WP_Term)#1207 (11) { ["term_id"]=> int(6) ["name"]=> string(39) "Electrical & Electronic Circuit Lab" ["slug"]=> string(33) "electrical-electronic-circuit-lab" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(6) ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "category" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(5) ["count"]=> int(2) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" ["image_id"]=> int(48) }

Comment: Yeah, `$term->name` should work. Where did you try and add it before?

Comment: I got this now. Thank you very much. I saved my day. Many many thanks